# Mapping with array as Key Or Value data type

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping

Is it possible to do a mapping with an Array as key/value ? Where an array would exist for each value ?

I'm actually looking to store structs in a mapping but can't seem to have it work.

```
Struct Foo{
uint x
}
```

`mapping(uint => Foo[])foo;` and even simply
`mapping([] => uint)foo` / `(uint => [])foo;` don't seems to work.

something so i can do :

`foo.1.push(FooInstance)`

`foo.1[0] = FooInstance`

Solidity Doc reads

> Mapping types are declared as mapping _KeyType => _ValueType, where _KeyType can be almost any type except for a mapping and _ValueType can actually be any type, including mappings.

So aren't array considered a data type in solidity?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Mappings can only use `elementary` types (`address`, `uint`, `bytes`, `string`) as keys, and more specifically any type for which `sha3()` is defined. This means structs and arrays currently can't be used as keys.

`mapping(uint => Foo[]) foo;` should work, and does for me. Your code has some syntax errors, which might be the problem (`struct` shouldn't be capitalized, `uint x` needs a semicolon)

`[]` is not a type, you need some elementary type in front of it, like `uint[]`.

Elements in arrays are accessed with bracket notation, not dot notation.

This contract should work:

```
contract Bar{

    struct Foo{
        uint x;
    }
    mapping(uint => Foo[]) foo;

    function add(uint id, uint _x) public {
        foo[id].push(Foo(_x));
    }

    function get(uint id, uint index) public returns(uint){
        return foo[id][index].x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep indeed i've just realized that i was coming here to answer my own question. Thanks you for the help!

Comment: Is there a way to return the whole array ?